# What is the mistake in read() and write() in C?

Tags: c

This is a small C program to test the client and server programs so that the client sends an integer to the client. The server multiplies the number by 10 and returns the integer*10 back to the client. When writing the integers to the FIFO.
This is my code so far:

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

main (void)
{
  int fda;      
  int fdb;      
  int number;
  int outputnumber;



  if((fda=open("FIFO_to_server", O_WRONLY))<0)
       printf("cant open fifo to write");

  if((fdb=open("FIFO_to_client", O_RDONLY))<0)
       printf("cant open fifo to read");

   printf("Client: Please enter an integer: ");
   scanf("%d", &number);


   write(fda, number, sizeof(number));
   printf("\nClient: Got the number sent, now waiting for response ");
   read(fdb, outputnumber, sizeof(outputnumber));
   printf("\nClient: received from server %s", outputnumber);

   close(fda);
   close(fdb);

   printf ("\nall done!\n");

 }
```

after compiling, I had some error:

```
-bash-3.2$ gcc clientHw.c -o client
 clientHw.c: In function `main':
 clientHw.c:36: warning: passing arg 2 of `write' makes pointer from integer 
 without a cast
 clientHw.c:38: warning: passing arg 2 of `read' makes pointer from integer 
 without a cast
```

Comment: `write(fda, &number, sizeof(number));` pass the address of the data

Comment: Since you're using `gcc` already, I bet that you would find turning on the `-Wall` option in compiling to be pretty helpful in diagnosing why your printf of outputnumber isn't showing what you expect.

Answer (score 3):

You must pass the address of the variables like this:

```
write(fda, &number, sizeof(number));
...
read(fdb, &outputnumber, sizeof(outputnumber));
```